# EF database first, rename entity table name

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have project with approach database first.
Tables this database have names kind GUID. I want  use human names  in code.
How i can change name entity, but no change table name in database?

Comment: Types should match. You have 2 options: 1. Change types for both. 2. Add new column for names and keep it unique and indexed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do that using EF Model Browser:

- Open Entity Model Browser
- Navigate to your entity under YourModel/Entity Types
- right click + Properties
- You can chance entity type name here

Or using designer:

- right click on your entity on the design pane + Properties from context menu
- Change **Name** property value

It will change generated entity class name without changing the database table nama.

Comment: If I understood question correctly OP wants to use `string`s containing human defined names and keep `uniqueidentifier` as type of sql field.

Comment: in database tableName = dvtable_5b607ffc_7ea2_47b1_90d4_bb72a0fe7280, in db.Context i want use tableName = Persons  instead dvtable_5b607ffc_7ea2_47b1_90d4_bb72a0fe7280

Comment: is it possible to change table name after compiled? or is it possible to make the table name to read from an Appsettings from .config file?