# Entity Framework database first, same table and column name mapping

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-database-first

In my data base I have table with name 'Site' which contains column 'Site' (please don't ask why :) )

I'm using database first approach. After updating model from data base I have entity 'Site' with property 'Site1'

```
public partial class Site
{
    ...
    public string Site1 { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

This works fine until I started usage of SqlQuery method with simple select:

```
context.Site.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM dbo.Site WHERE SiteID IN(2,1)").ToArray();
```

In result of this I receive error: 'The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'aapModel.Site'. A member of the type, 'Site1', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.'

I have found one solution to change column name in query:

```
context.Site.SqlQuery("SELECT Site as Site1 FROM dbo.Site WHERE SiteID IN(2,1)").ToArray();
```

But it's not flexible and elegant.
Is there a way to say entity framework to don't change columns names while generating model from database?

Comment: Try changing the name manually: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20780489/ef-database-first-rename-entity-table-name

Comment: Unfortunately: The name Site cannot be duplicated in this context. Please choose another name.

Comment: I think there is no way to do this. When using SqlQuery, you should have  knowledge of the property name (in entity type) and column name (in database table). That's why we rarely have to use SqlQuery.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
public partial class Site
{
    [Column("Site1")]
    public string Site1 { get; set; }

}
```

I notice that your class is a partial, are your sure you don't have a mapping class of your entity model ?