# Rename entity of exisisitng project c# database first

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have ongoing windows application that developed by using entity framework database first approach. Suddenly i changed table names of all the tables in the data base, which means i added table prefix for every table. (ex: abc table to A_abc).

now i want to change the entity name also. but i can't change because the class name is using in the code. if i rename the entity class i have to rename also the coding according to new class name.

i need solution for this.please help!

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you not mapping the entity and the table name somewhere?

In Code First Approach we can do this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Abc>().ToTable("t_Abc");
```

a. Is it not possible to override "OnModelCreating" in Database First, and map the entity and table as mentioned in the above code.

b. In Database First Approach, I haven't tried this; Let me know if this helps you.

[Renaming Entity in DF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20780489/ef-database-first-rename-entity-table-name)

Comment: Thank Balaji. i tried option (b) it's only changing the entity name but inside the project class name is not renaming i have to change each one by one.

Comment: Thanks balaji. Still working on this and i will get back to you once i check this option.