# Change schema object name on Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to make a Test enviroment on my project so I copy PROD database in another host.

On new host I can't set schema object name so I'm using default schema obj which is `dbo` and in PROD is `project_name`.

Example:
Looks like **"dbo.Table"** in TEST.
Looks like **"project_name.table"** in PROD.

I copy and pasted my ASP.NET project and I changed my source connection.

The problem is that the program has a reference to `project_name.Users` and I want to change it by `dbo.Users`. I already updated the connection but I can't change schema obj name.

How can I refer to the correct table?

**Error :**

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: 'An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.'
>   SqlException: Invalid object name 'project_name.Users'.

Comment: which approach you are using of entity framework? Code-First or DB-First?

Comment: @HardikLeuwa i'm using DB-First

Comment: Hope this may help you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20780489/ef-database-first-rename-entity-table-name

Answer (score 0):

You can use annotation to define the database table that a class is mapped to

```
[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.Table("dbo.Table")]
public class Table {
...
}
```