# EF Core 5 - DB First - Naming of navigation properties (InverseProperty)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-5

We use EF Core 5.0.4 with DB first approach. In the current project we have the situation that the generated names of navigation properties are not ideal.
The naming works fine if we link tables with primary/foreign keys. In our case we link multiple tables (with data to be translated) to a translation table with a unique index (translation key). So every table with data to be translated have a unique index and the translation table has a primary key on the translation key and languge code.

In this case EF generates names like this:

```
[ForeignKey(nameof(LanguageCode))]
[InverseProperty(nameof(Language.TranslationLanguageCodeNavigations))]
public virtual Language LanguageCodeNavigation { get; set; }

public virtual DeviceType TranslationKey1 { get; set; }
public virtual TransportUnit TranslationKey2 { get; set; }
public virtual News TranslationKey3 { get; set; }
public virtual News TranslationKey4 { get; set; }
public virtual Consumable TranslationKeyNavigation { get; set; }
```

So it is not possible to see, which TranslationKey belongs to which field on the example "News". This table has two fields that gets translated. The only way to find out is to have a look in the generated context. But there is no guarantee the numbers of the key will be the same, when we generate the context the next time.

Is it somehow possible to control the generated names? Generate the context and then use CodeFirst approach is not an option.

Comment: Not sure if this could help but have you tried changing the name using the EF model browser? https://stackoverflow.com/a/20780542/6138713

Comment: What db provider are you using?

Comment: I am using the SQL server provider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use handlebars templates:

https://github.com/TrackableEntities/EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Handlebars

> Scaffold EF Core models using Handlebars templates.

> Uses Handlebars.NET to compile Handlebars templates when generating
> models with the Entity Framework Core scaffolding tools.

You will have a ScaffoldingDesignTimeServices class where to define  lot of things on the generation of your dbcontext and also handlebars templates that you can customize, the templates will be used when creating your entities by scaffolding

```
        // Add Handlebars transformer for Country property
    services.AddHandlebarsTransformers(
        propertyTransformer: e =>
            e.PropertyName == "Country"
                ? new EntityPropertyInfo("Country", e.PropertyName, false)
                : new EntityPropertyInfo(e.PropertyType, e.PropertyName, e.PropertyIsNullable));

    // Add optional Handlebars transformers
    //services.AddHandlebarsTransformers(
    //    entityNameTransformer: n => n + "Foo",
    //    entityFileNameTransformer: n => n + "Foo",
    //    constructorTransformer: e => new EntityPropertyInfo(e.PropertyType + "Foo", e.PropertyName + "Foo"),
    //    propertyTransformer: e => new EntityPropertyInfo(e.PropertyType, e.PropertyName + "Foo"),
    //    navPropertyTransformer: e => new EntityPropertyInfo(e.PropertyType + "Foo", e.PropertyName + "Foo"));
```

This can evolve with your codebase/DB, keeping  the scaffolding files and templates into source control will give you a reliable way of creating the desired dbcontext with the evolution of your software/db

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It sounds promising. I'll give it a try tomorrow

Comment: It doesn't work yet - I am still figuring out how the whole Scaffold with Handbars works. But I could already solve another problem with these handlebars.